# suitable convex loss function for a vector whose outer product with itself goes to given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Say, I have some convex objective function w.r.t an optimization value vector x(e.x linear w.r.t x)

I'd like to minimize the objective plus, make outer product of x with itself to be similar to given positive semidefinite matrix X (i.e $xx^T \sim X$)

To make it, I want a suitable convex loss(penalty) function

Is there any suitable convex loss function?

it's okay if you can make a convex problem by adding some constraint though the loss itself is not always convex

(I checked frobenius norm but the hessian of $ ||X-xx^T||$ gives $-4X+4(x^Tx)I+8xx^T$. Thus it is not convex. If I addition the constraint $X \le (x^Tx)I+2xx^T$, the loss function is convex in the feasible set. However, the constraint is not suit to a convex problem because right hand side is convex function. Constraint for a convex problem should be (convex function <= 0) form )

Comment: How about [Schatten Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm)? And specifically Nuclear Norm?

Comment: hi @Royi anything is ok if it is convex. But then is it a convex? Nuclear_Norm(X-xx^T) is convex?? how can I prove it?

Comment: I'm not sure as you plug in non linear function of $ x $. What about trying to linearize one of the Norms?

Comment: yes nonlinear term makes me hard to solve it. What does "linearizing one of the norms" mean?

Comment: Try using approximation of the norm with respect to your term. Just like a Taylor Series of your object function.

Comment: It might be helpful because in my problem setting x is above -1 and below 1 but not sure whether it works. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You're out of luck here. There is no convex loss function in this case. You'll have to go with a relaxation method.